# Uploading PHP files with FileZilla in binary mode sometimes result in error

Tags: ftp, php, character-encoding, filezilla

This is related to [the issue where downloading files in Filezilla results in \r\n\n newlines](https://superuser.com/questions/39520/downloading-files-with-filezilla-result-in-newline-r-n-n). The answer suggests downloading then in binary, which works. However, there is a problem uploading which sometimes cause errors where the server place 2 lines onto 1 line resulting in error. Besides uploading in ASCII and downloading binary manually, is there a way to setup FileZilla for auto converting while uploading, and binary only when downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set to switch transfer modes between upload or download by setting preferences. At least not in the current version of 3.2

Right now you're just stuck with going to the menu when you want to download or upload and switch by the options present.

> Transfer > Transfer type

And then manually set the current upload or download action transfer in auto detect, ASCII or binary.